# How to achieve textured matte paint finish on flat aluminium

Tags: aluminum

I have aluminium gates, made of sheets.  If I paint it using normal powder coating, it looks shiny and reveals imperfections (e.g. mild bends) depending on the angle at which sun light hits it.

I am thinking to finish it in such a way that it looks *textured* and *matte*.

Any thoughts of durable approaches for outdoor use?

Comment: try different mechanical operations to get good cosmetic surface texture in the metal part... sanding, sand blast, bead blast, tumbling, wire brush... Sometimes for small surface defects, a different primer can fix paint, but don't know if there's something like that for powder coat

Comment: @PeteW - am I limited to powder coating?  Can I use other types

Comment: I am less familiar with powder coating. (Have ordered it and parts magically come back, don't know any details). Don't know if there are options e.g. for thicker coating. Primers that fill tiny void type imperfections is something I've done for spray paint (one-offs). Good results but inefficient. Tumbling/blasting etc would be good for most  metal, again for even texture. If it's more of a stretch mark from the forming, might not be enough. Picture might help.

Comment: @PeteW - That's fine, I'd like to know the other options.  I'm flexible.  Is there any other type of coating that is as durable as powder coating?

Answer (score 2):

Using "normal" powder coating excludes the option to use a matte finish powder coating. If the service you are using for the coating has not presented to you this option, they are derelict in their business.

Additionally, there are powders available, when properly applied, provide for a wrinkle finish, addressing the textured consideration in your post. Another texture available is an irregular "beaded-up" finish, which consists of random small islands on the surface interspersed with matte finish flat portions.

Obviously, if you are performing the powder coating, it's not dereliction, it's simply not being aware of the options available.

*source: direct, frequent contact with personal friend's powder coating business*

Comment: Any non-powdercoating methods that will give a durable and good matte finish for aluminium?  (and yes, they're derelict).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not stuck on powdercoating, there are "hammered metal" paints.

[Rust-oleum rattle cans](https://www.google.com/search?q=hammered+metal+spray+paint&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&sxsrf=AOaemvI0Gye1EtG452wwTRHID2dwnJrgBA:1630233033659&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=KBZHeUeIYmBLhM%252CIal2-2q3SM90KM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kQXxfaqpt8rXV-W9QO9h1JqmCfVFg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjW6Pymg9byAhV9SjABHU4TBXoQ9QF6BAgOEAE&biw=1093&bih=500#imgrc=KBZHeUeIYmBLhM)

Comment: Can it be applied on existing powder coated paint layer?  Or is it better to remove old powder coated paint?

Comment: But yes, I'm not stuck on any specific paint type.

Comment: Does the hammered metal paint come in matte?  What I've seen so far is the shiny ones.